# For any representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, if $0$ is not a weight then $\alpha/2$ is.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\pi$ be an finite dimensional continous representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$. Let $\alpha$ be the root corresponding to $\alpha(H)=2$. Show that if $0$ is not a weight then $\alpha/2$ is.

I know that all the weights of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ lie in $1/2\mathbb Z\alpha$. But I do not see how to use that $V_0$ is empty to show that $V_{\alpha/2}$ is not empty?

Update:
Suppose $0\notin \Lambda(\pi)$. There must be some highest weight $\lambda$. Then we have $Hv=\lambda v$ for some $v$. Note that this also gives that $-\lambda$ is also a weight. I know that for $v\in V_\lambda$ it follows that $Yv\in V_{\lambda-\alpha}$ if I could show that $Y^nv$ was non zero for all $n$ such that $-\lambda<\lambda - n\alpha<\lambda$ then we would be done. But I can't see why this must be true?

Comment: Starting from a highest weight and given that $0$ is not a weight, what can you conclude about that highest weight?

Comment: Also, have you not looked at easy examples? Like the standard representation, or the adjoint representation? That usually gives ideas.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Let $\omega$ be the highest weight and let $v\in V_{\omega}$. Then we can get $Y^nv\in V_{\omega-n\alpha/2}$ or should this be $ V_{\omega-2n}$? If this was true for all $n$ we would have $\omega-n\alpha/2\neq 0$ for all $n$ since $0$ is not a weight? So $\omega$ must be an integer multiple of $\alpha$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg  I will try do this

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft is this update along the right track?